# Laptop with multiple Windows - what options to set? (chkdsk killed Windows XP)

Tags: windows

I have a special laptop with 5 OS: debian + grub, DOS, Win XP, Win 7, Win 8.1.
grub is bootloader, everything works fine.

But some time ago it happened that suddenly one chkdsk came into play, when booting into a windows. Afterwards the windows XP did not work anymore, I had to reinstall XP.

Does anybody know, why chkdsk (done after grub before windowsstart) killed XP?

What can I do to prevent the windows OS from killing each other?

Besides that, what other options would you set (in general)?

I already set HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\BootExecute to blank in all Windows.
https://www.maketecheasier.com/cancel-scheduled-chkdsk-operations-windows/

Comment: Have you checked the SMART data regarding the health of your hard drive?  Generally, chkdsk checks and fixes the disk equivalent of table of contents.  If you do a /R is checks the surface, but problems with chkdsk usually indicate the hard drive its self has errors. After looking at SMART, I would do a chkdsk /r on each OS to see if the other OS have undiscovered bad sectors.  Depending on the results you may need a new hard drive.

Comment: Thank you, I will do this. But the Hard Drive is a SSD, 1 month old. Would this hit too, on a 1 month SSD?

Comment: As a general rule no an SSD should not have visible bad sectors.  The SSD has a ton of spare sectors, and bad sectors are generally remap totally transparently to the user on a SSD.  Look at the Power_On_Hours in the SMART data does that number approx match the number of hours your laptop was ON for the last month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should never, ever, absolutely never, let one operating system do chkdsk
of another, if they are not of the same operating system version.
You can never foresee the result - it might work or it might destroy.

Windows disk formats evolve with each major release. Backwards compatibility
is rather good, but forward compatibility is non-existent.

I suggest in each operating system to hide the partitions of the others.
You may hide drives by three methods:

- Disk Management : Right-click the partition, choose
  "Change Letter and Paths" and click on Remove.
- Group Policy : Run `gpedit.msc and` navigate to the key

  ```
  User Configuration/Administrative Templates/Windows Components/File Explorer
  ```

  Double-click "Hide these specified drives in My Computer" and select Enabled.

You should do this in each Windows instance where one of the methods is possible.

Try also to correctly shut-down each operating system, so chkdsk is not required.